# Translation in discord.py bot doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, google-translate

I've been trying to make my discord bot translate texts using a module called googletrans. It seems fairly simple and it should have worked without any hassle, or so I thought.

So after my import statements, I have `translator = Translator()`.
My following cog code is:

```
@commands.command(aliases=["tl", "Tl", "Translate"])
    async def translate(self, ctx, *, message):
        language = translator.detect(message)
        translation = translator.translate(message)
        embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_theme())
        embed.add_field(name=f"Language: {language} ", value=f'{translation}')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But it shows this error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.`
Where am I going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: the full traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in command translate:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\cogs\translate.py", line 13, in translate
    language = translator.detect(message)
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 255, in detect
    data = self._translate(text, 'en', 'auto', kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with commands.group() somewhere. Could you provide more code if you do use commands.group please? It doesn't look like there's a problem with the codeblock itself according to traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same problem. Installing alpha version of google trans helped, so try doing this:

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

And:

```
from googletrans import Translator

@client.command()
async def translate(ctx, lang, *, thing):
    translator = Translator()
    translation = translator.translate(thing, dest=lang)
    await ctx.send(translation.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comments since I do not have enough reputation, so I will edit this post once I get more information about your code.

Could you please upload the full traceback? Also what happens if before calling the method `group` on the object, you ensures that it is not None ? (I don't know if this is in your code or in the library)

Have you tried debugging and checking at each step what the variables are and if they are not what you think they should be

Finally, I also think that maybe your variable message is always empty, since you catch other parameters with * right before message so this makes the message parameter a keyword-only parameter, which, to the best of my knowledge cannot be passed when using a bot command

Have you tried changing your function's signature to this :

```
async def translate(self, ctx, message):
```

?

UPDATE : From what it seems, the problem happens inside the library, however this can happen if the parameter given to the library function is ill-formed.

If you simulate the bot command (await the method in a main file with ctx=None and message="Hello my friend, how are you today ? I hope you are fine"), what happens?

As can be seen on the [pypi page about googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) on section "Language detection", most of the time the function is called with a sentence. Maybe if the sentence is short enough, the detection does not work ?

Also, I think you should indicate in your question what library you are using because there is also [Google's official translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs?hl=en) that can be used

Comment: i did change my function's signature to ```async def translate(self, ctx, message):```, but it still shows the same error. i have added the full traceback now, please look into it.

Comment: Have you tried printing the variable `message` once the method is called? does it correspond to the argument you are trying to pass? And does that argument correspond to what the function `translator.detect` expect? 
You could also try to use [python typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) (at least for the variable message) so that it'll looks like this async def translate(self, ctx: discord.ext.commands.Context, message: str):`. This allows for automatic casting when the command is called and also helps your IDE with auto complete